# Custom Post Type Slug Rewrite Issues

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type, slug

To put a long story short, I'm trying to get the custom post type category to show where it says 'project-item' as you can see [HERE](http://celtexperience.com/project_item/celt-la-tene-3-3-hoppy-bitter-with-video/)

I presume it has something to do with the way I've registered the custom post type such as in this code:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'register_posts' );
function register_posts() {

    register_post_type( 'team_post',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( "Team" ,"um_lang"),
                'singular_name' => __( "Team" ,"um_lang")
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,              
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => "project_item", 'with_front' => TRUE),
            'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','page-attributes')             
        )
    );

    register_post_type( 'project_post',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( "Projects","um_lang"),
                'singular_name' => __( "Project" ,"um_lang")
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,              
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => "project_item", 'with_front' => TRUE),
            'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','page-attributes')             
        )
    );

    register_taxonomy('project_category',array (
      0 => 'project_post',
    ),array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => __('Projects Category',"um_lang"),'show_ui' => true,'query_var' => true,'singular_label' => __('Projects Category',"um_lang")) );

}
?>
```

Comment: Recently, I face this issue. **Solved!** [#188834][1]


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94817/add-category-base-to-url-in-custom-post-type-taxonomy/188834#188834

Answer (score 1):

This tells wordpress to insert the text project_item into the slug, which is what is happening:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => "project_item", 'with_front' => TRUE)
```

And this says to insert the value of project_item:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => "%project_item%", 'with_front' => TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried that and it came up with a server error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
global $wp_rewrite;
$movies_structure = '/movies/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%movies%';
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%movies%", '([^/]+)', "movies=");
$wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('movies', $movies_structure, false);
```

return link:

```
domain.com/movies/movie_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I installed this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

Then instead of using %categories% (Which didn't work) I used the specific custom post type category name (which was %project_category%)

Comment: try my solution above, replacing 'project_item' with 'project_category'.  so 'rewrite' => array('slug' => "%project_category%", 'with_front' => TRUE)

Comment: I've tried that but it just shows the URL as exampleurl/%projectcategory%/post-name